# Insert in multiple tables after insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem with inserting a stored procedure in SQL server.
I want to insert something in multiple tables after a if statement

```
BEGIN
 insert into BIJDRAGE VALUES(@accountID, @datum, @soort);

 DECLARE @bijdrageid int;
 SET @bijdrageid = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM BIJDRAGE)

if (@soort ='bericht')

 insert into BERICHT values (@bijdrageid, @titel, @inhoud) 
 insert into BIJDRAGE_BERICHT values (@id, @bijdrageid);

/////////This above doesnt work\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

else if @soort= 'bestand' insert into  BESTAND values ((select max(id) from BIJDRAGE), @categorieID, @bestandsLocatie, @grootte)


else insert into CATEGORIE values((select max(id) from BIJDRAGE), @categorieID, @naam)
END
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: I am assuming that all variables (except bijdrageid) are passed in to the stored procedure. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CreateNew, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

Comment: If you're going to be executing more than one statement inside the IF, you need a BEGIN and END.

Comment: I would also suggest using the OUTPUT clause (or SCOPE_IDENTITY if it is an identity) in your original insert instead of immediately selecting the value you inserted. You have a race condition here that will work correctly most of the time, but not always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bijdrageid int
    insert into BIJDRAGE VALUES(@accountID, @datum, @soort)

    SELECT @bijdrageid = MAX(id) 
    FROM BIJDRAGE

    IF(@soort ='bericht')
    BEGIN

     insert into BERICHT values (@bijdrageid, @titel, @inhoud) 

     insert into BIJDRAGE_BERICHT values (@id, @bijdrageid)

    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @soort= 'bestand' 
        BEGIN
            insert into  BESTAND values (@bijdrageid, @categorieID, @bestandsLocatie, @grootte)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            insert into CATEGORIE values(@bijdrageid, @categorieID, @naam)
        END
    END
END
```